# The intersections of three polygons in a square with area $=6$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Let three convex polygons with areas equal to $3$, in a square with area equals to $6$. We need to prove that there are two of them which has their intersection with area is at least $1$. I have no idea for this question? Any hints? How to write the details solution?

Comment: The statement of the problem is unclear.  The phrase "in a square with area = 6" seems to say it is the area of the square which is 6.  But this doesn't imply anything about the intersection of the convex polygons being at least 1, or even that the union of the three polygons has area at least 1.  Presumably you wanted to assume something about the convex polygons, but as given these could be arbitrarily small, even having empty intersections.

Comment: Perhaps the statement should about three convex polygons in a $2\times 2$ square such that the sum of the areas of the three contained polygons is 6?

Comment: I forgot the important hypothesis that: polygons must have areas equal to $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: inclusion-exclusion.  Convexity is irrelevant, as is the fact it's in a square.

Comment: Please more details

Comment: $m(A\cup B \cup C) = m(A) + m(B) + m(C) - m(A\cap B) - m(A \cap C) - m(B \cap C) + m(A \cap B \cap C)$